Calling unmanaged C\C++ DLL methods from Java?
I've been looking at a lot of examples on how to call unmanaged DLL methods from Java using JNI but none of them show the actual calling of the DLL methods. All the examples I've seen  just print "Hello World" or add 2 numbers together. Here is some code to show what I'm talking about.
public class NativeClassWrapper {

    public static native void userLogin(int id, char[] username, char[] password);
    
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("User.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        userLogin(100000, "user123\0".toCharArray(), "password123\0".toCharArray()); 
    }
}

// javac -h NativeClassWrapper.java generate C header

/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class NativeClassWrapper */

#ifndef _Included_NativeClassWrapper
#define _Included_NativeClassWrapper
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_dll_call_NativeClassWrapper_userLogin
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jcharArray, jcharArray);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif


At this point I am lost as to how I actually call my 12yr old unmanaged C/C++ DLL method. Do I have to create a whole new duplicate copy of the CPP class file and rename all the methods to match the methods names that were generated by JNI and create a whole new DLL? In C# I didn't have to do anything like that hence my question.
TIA

Java 22 has the Foreign Function and Memory (FFM) API which improves on and supplants JNI. Have you looked into using this instead? For reference Foreign Function and Memory API as well as: JEP 454: Foreign Function & Memory API

Thanks for the replies. I'll check into the suggestions

Those of use compiling to "native code" also don't like it to be called "unmanaged". :-)

@BoP Well, something has to be what makes Java so s-l-o-o-o-w.  I guess it's the "management".  (And not a complete joke, either.  Just benchmark CPU-intensive operations, like OpenSSL vs BouncyCastle for AES/GCM encryption...)

Yes, when using JNI, you have to wrap those methods in new methods written in C/C++ which abide by the calling conventions required by JNI and perform a lot of additional bureaucratic stuff, for example pinning objects in memory so that the garbage collector will not move them around while your core C/C++ code is trying to access them.
Have you looked at Java Native Access (JNA) instead of JNI? It might make things easier.
Or, starting with Java 22, Foreign Function and Memory (FFM) as Hovercraft Full of Eels suggested in a comment; it is probably more fresh than JNA.

Thanks for confirming. What a pain.

To be honest, if you are planning on interfacing with C++, then C# is a better choice than Java.  With FFM they might have fixed that, but my guess is that they have just made it less of a pain. I cannot imagine the Java world coming up with anything nearly as convenient as the P/Invoke mechanism of C#.

Its literally two lines of code to get access to a DLL from C# but I'm stuck with a Java based web server that has to call the DLL.
